# Updating Ionic Apps in real time

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm a web developer, new to Ionic.But I can't find out how can I update my app on the server,like a website,and without having user redownload the app.Is there any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of recently there is a solution for this. Ionic calls it `Ionic Deploy`, and you can see the official documentation about it [here](http://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/).

However, one must note that this is still in Alpha version and they don't recommend it for production, but since they're very apt in shipping new features, I'm sure this will be even production ready very soon.

Comment: Seems the location of this changed - it is [here](http://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/) now.

Comment: @TomerCagan: you're right. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's an available plugin you can use [Cordova-hot-code-push](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push)

This plugin provides functionality to perform automatic updates of the web based content in your application.Basically, everything that is stored in www folder of your Cordova project can be updated using this plugin.

supported platforms: Android 4.0.0 or above.
iOS 7.0 or above. Xcode 7 is required.

It has a great [wiki](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push/wiki) too.